# Problemas com arquivos javascripts inseridos na Masterpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Não consigo utiliziar uma função [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) contida em um arquivo que está inserido em uma MasterPage. Onde posso estou errando?

Segue tag  da MasterPage

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Formatacao.js"></script>


    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o problema esteja na hierarquia dos seus arquivos, por exemplo:

```
--- Aplicacao/
    ---- Scripts/
    ---- Content/
    ---- MinhaPasta/
         ---- MinhaPaginaQueNaoFunciona.aspx
    ---- Site.Master
```

O que acontece é que quando você entra na `MinhaPasta` pra você acessar os arquivos da pasta `Scripts` não funciona o `src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"` porque ele interpreta como `src="MinhaPasta/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"`

Pra resolver esse problema de diretórios você pode utilizar o [`.ResolveUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl(v=vs.110).aspx), dessa forma:

```
<link href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/css/bootstrap.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/Formatacao.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Só perdi o css. Mas eu voltei o antigo.